# How to attach file from Google Drive in PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

May I know how to attach a file from Google Drive in PHP. I want to make it like this. Thanks.
[image: see the image]

Comment: you need to integrate google drive to your application. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Recently google drive has released its version 3 of Google Drive API unless you can use an earlier version as you wish.

link :
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

step by step guide provided by google

Make sure that you have enables the sufficient PHP version (hope its>= 5.4) and the composer manager to handle the dependencies on the API.

Comment: Is this your answer? @anom